# Exchange JMS message across managed servers in weblogic

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

Note: I have a client who doesn't have a weblogic cluster license. We have configure two managed servers and each of them have a JMSServers.

Problem: Information is cached from database. When someone modifies the database entry through backend job, there will be a notification to update the cache. That notification should be posted to a queue or topic in each of the managed server.

I tried SAF topic, but it was not able to post messages to local and remote topic.

How do I exchange messages reliably between two managed servers without a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done.

Assuming there are three weblogic managed servers (MSERVER-01, MSERVER-02, MSERVER-03) and the person who reads this message knows to create a domain, managed server, JMS Server, JMS Module, JMS Connection factory, JMS Topic, JMS Message Bridge destinations and last Bridges.

**Steps to solve the problem:**

1. Create three JMSServers, one for each of the server listed above.
2. Create 3 JMS Module targetting to each of the JMS Server
3. In each of the JMS Module create a Connection Factory with default target
4. In each of the JMS Module create 2 TOPICS, one named as NOTIFICATION_MANAGER_TOPIC another MSG_PROCESSOR_TOPIC.
5. Create Source Message Bridge Destinations pointing to each of the NOTIFICATION_MANAGER_TOPIC as N1, N2, N3
6. Create target Message Bridge Destinations pointing to each of the MSG_PROCESSOR_TOPIC as P1, P2, P3
7. Create Bridges as N1 to P1, N1 to P2, N1 to P3
8. Create Bridges as N2 to P1, N2 to P2, N2 to P3
9. Create Bridges as N3 to P1, N3 to P2, N3 to P3

Once the message bridges are ready, you may use the following sample code to post messages to N1 (the NOTIFICATION_MANAGER_TOPIC) and you will see that messages are passed into all the MSG_PROCESSOR_TOPIC that is P1, P2, P3.

Note: Bridges are not ideal for communication within the domain. This is just a workaround for people who don't have weblogic cluster license which is required for creating distributed topics. Also, you may try SAF (Store and Forward) instead of Bridge.